# Override the volume view on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Apps like Snapchat and Instagram change the way the default change volume alert looks.

Default view:

[image]

Snapchat:

[image]

Instagram:

[image]

Two questions:

1. How is this done?
2. Is this even allowed with Apple's Human Interface Guidelines and App Review? Will changing this cause your app to be rejected from the App Store?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [JPSVolumeButtonHandler](https://github.com/jpsim/JPSVolumeButtonHandler) to override the volume buttons.

Then, to control the volume yourself, you could use:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
...
[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:(float)volume];
```

Please note that this function was deprecated on iOS 7, but still works today, even on iOS 9.

As far as getting your app rejected from the App Store, people reported that they didn't have any issue by using this pod, but your mileage may vary.